# How to automate Unigine Heaven using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, benchmarking

I was trying to automate the Unigine Heaven Benchmark using python.
But I am unable to fetch the keys as those are mutable in API of Unigine Heaven eg. Run option is not working using python code for me.

Please provide the solution.

The code is :

```
import sys 
import os 
from pywinauto.application import Application 
def heaven(): 
    Application().Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Unigine\Heaven Benchmark 4.0\heaven.bat") 

heaven()
```

So after running this that Benchmark is opening and API it is showing. But in that benchmark clicking of API buttons i am unable to do.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have written code like:

import sys
import os
from pywinauto.application import Application

def heaven():
Application().Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Unigine\Heaven Benchmark 4.0\heaven.bat")

So after running this that Benchmark is opening and API it is showing.
But in that benchmark clicking of API buttons i am unable to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have hit similar snag. However, I figured that in basic edition, the command line option is not supported. 
As a workaround, you can look into the the file of 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Unigine\Heaven Benchmark 4.0\data\launcher\js\heaven-ui-logic

Change the following in the last

```
//  $('#run').click(startBenchmark);
startBenchmark();
```

And click heaven.bat. It should trigger workload without the RUN button requiring click.